# build php with Debug symbols

Tags: php, macos, debugging

I installed php on my Mac Os using the install script provided by here [this is a link to an install.sh file created by https://liip.ch](https://php-osx.liip.ch/install.sh) (as it was recommended by an online blog post). Looking at the phpinfo.php file, it says `Debug Build: no`. It doesn't give an option in the install script to set the Debug Build to `yes`. How can I rebuild the build created by the install script to get the debug build?

Comment: You can turn it on in the php.ini file, take a look on how to enable x-debug on apache/nginx or whatever server you're running php on

Comment: Look into `x-debug`.

Comment: Do you want to debug *the internals of PHP itself* (this is what "Debug Build" refers to) or do you want to debug *the PHP scripts you run* (this is what [XDebug](http://xdebug.org/) is for)?

Comment: @IMSoP thank you for clarifying the distinction. It was intended to debug scripts that I run, but I'll leave the question nevertheless

Comment: @Leahcim then you will need to setup xdebug in your php.ini (both for cli and apache), as well as have an IDE that can properly interpret the xdebug php->ide protocol and give you the symbolic debugging you need in your php scripts.  Also : when setting up, beware if you are using php-fpm.  At some time, xdebug and php-fpm shipped with the same default port (9000) ... you may have to skit around that in your setupts.